# Нужно записать число в переменую с сайта

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть вот такой кусок кода

```
<text data="pill-value" dy="21.29" dx="21" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 17px; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: AvenirNext, Arial, Verdana; font-weight: 500; opacity: 1;">20</text>
```

Мне нужно отсюда взять число которое находиться между тегами text и записать в переменную. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `jquery` (Скачать можешь от [сюда](https://code.jquery.com/)):

```
$('text').text();
```

Сначала только сделай `$(document).ready(function () { //Code });`

Итоговое решение:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let text_val = $('text').text();
});
```